# Form submission in php

Tags: php, arrays, forms, function

I have a little problem with my `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` code. What I want is to run the `processForm()` function when the submit button for the form has been clicked. The problem is that when I include the `if(isset($_POST['submit']))` function, when I click on the submit button the `processFunction()` does not run at all.but when i include `if( !isset($_POST['submit']))` the `processForm()` function runs... Why is this and can you help me out with this issue please

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Membership Form</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .error { background: #d33; color: white; padding: 0.2em; }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>

    <?php 
        if ( isset($_POST["submit"])) { //if submit input has value
                        processForm();//calls the processForm function
                    }

        function processForm(){ 

            $compulsaryForm = array("firstName" , "lastName", "password" , "passwordRetype");
            $missingFields = array();

            foreach ($compulsaryForm as $input) { //loop
                if (!isset($_POST[$input])) {
                    $missingFields[] = $input;
                } // forget the else part cause we mainly want to avoid the warning msg
            }

            if ($missingFields) {
                echo "<p>there are missingFields</p>";
            }

        }

     ?>

<form action="htmlForms2.php" method="post">

    *name:<input type="text" name="firstName"> <br><br>
    *last name: <input type="text" name="lastName"> <br><br>
    *password<input type="password" name="password"> <br><br>
    *retype password<input type="password" name="passwordRetype"><br><br>

    male:<input type="radio" name="sex"><br>
    female:<input type="radio" name="sex"><br>

    favourite food:<select name = "favourite">
                        <option value="select">select</option>
                        <option value="rice">rice</option>
                        <option value="beans">beans</option>
                    </select><br>

    do you want to recieve news letter?<input type="checkbox" name="newsLetter"><br>

    Any comments? :<input type="text" name="comments"><br>

    <input type="reset" name="reset">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: the shown code should work (as far as the isset is concerned).Please do a `var_dump($_POST);` before this `if` to see what you've got in there.

Comment: _sidenote:_ you will want to set values to your radio "sex".

Comment: Your function definition is after your first call to the function.  Try moving the function definition to before your `if-then`.  Otherwise Jeff is correct - it *should* work

Comment: can you var_dump the $_POST , also you can use !empty instead of isset

Comment: _sidenote:_ this `if (!isset($_POST[$input]))` will not work as you'd expect. An empty firstName like "" will be 'set'. You wanna check for `empty()` maybe.

Comment: Hi, as said by @Jeff this it's when lies the problem, the `processForm` is effectively called, but the `!isset($_POST[$input]` inside the loop will return `false` and thus wouldn't enter the condition: `isset` on an array check if the key is present in the array and this is the case here `$_POST` comes with all the `names` submitted by the form even if empty.

Comment: I know I'm repeating what was already said about what @Jeff said. However, if you're going to want to also check if the checkbox was selected, you're going to have to add an additional conditional statement using `isset()` for it. This isn't too complicated, but it should be done that way should you decide to check for that also; this applies to checkboxes and radios. Personally, I feel this is a typographical error.

Comment: "sidenote: this if (!isset($_POST[$input])) will not work as you'd expect. An empty firstName like "" will be 'set'. You wanna check for empty() maybe." ya the empty() function solved the problem...thank you very much jeff

Answer (score 0):

your code looks fine in terms of the "submit" field validation. What does not looks fine are these lines:

```
$compulsaryForm = array("firstName" , "lastName", "password" , "passwordRetype");
$missingFields = array();

foreach ($compulsaryForm as $input) { //loop
  if (!isset($_POST[$input])) {
    ...
```

All the inputs you're validating against will be sent in the submission, so `isset(...)` will be `true`, they **may be empty** but they will exist for sure. So validate your **emptyness** on the server side or before sending the form, or even better in both places and it should work ;)

```
// Use: count($_POST[$input]) < 5, In case you want to validate the text length 
if ( !isset($_POST[$input]) || empty($_POST[$input]) || count($_POST[$input]) < 5 {
```